# ¿Por que tengo este error al importar una librería si acabo de instalar los paquetes nuget?

Tags: formularios, xamarin, nuget

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto todo funcionaba super bien, y hoy cuando volví a abrirlo y empezar a trabajar de nuevo en el código me da error y no compila.

Este es el error:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (UnapMovilV5.iOS)

¿Alguien tiene una idea de que puede ser?

Comment: Pero cual es el error que te da???

Comment: Deberías adjuntar el error que te sale, y decir que paquete instalaste para ser más específico y ayudarte con el problema.

Comment: Eric Bienvenido, Te recomiendo que veas [ask] y [mcve]. Tal como has escrito tu pregunta lo más que probable es que termine cerrada, revisa los enlaces y ve si puedes editarla agregando mayor detalle e información. Saludos

Comment: Editado, no me habia dado cuenta que el error no habia sido escrito.

Comment: Has intentado a volver a instalar el paquete por si acaso?

Comment: Si están todos los paquetes instalados, pero el error me sigue saliendo

Comment: En tu proyecto, existe la referencia a `Newtonsoft...`?

Comment: Agregadas las referencias @Pikoh

Comment: Si tienes los `using` correspondientes y las referencias agregadas, ya no se que puede ser. Sin ver la solución es muy dificil ayudarte mas,lo siento

Comment: A veces un Clean + Build solucionan estos problemas. ¿tienes un solo proyecto en la solucion?¿el proyecto donde esta el Json.Net es el mismo del de iOS?